# Relationship between an affine variety $V \subset \Bbb A^n$ and $I(V)$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've been reading an introductory book on algebraic geometry and we've defined affine varities and now looking at the ideals of those varieties.

I am trying to get a geometric picture about the situation where I have an affine variety $V \subset \Bbb A^n$ and an ideal $I(V)=\{f \in \Bbb C[x_1, \dots x_n] : f(x)= 0, \forall x \in V\}$.

As an example if I take the $x$-axis and the $yz-$plane of $\Bbb R^3$ I have $V=\Bbb V(xy,xz) = \{(x,y,z) : xy=0,xz=0 \}$. Now the ideal $$I(V)=\{f \in \Bbb C[x,y,z] : f(x)=0, \forall x \in V\}$$ consists of polynomials such that they vanish on all points of $V$.

Is it correct to think of this pictoirally as polynomials that intersect the $x$-axis and the $yz$-plane? I've attached a picture to explain the idea I thought.

[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOaM1.png)

Comment: This doesn't really make a lot of sense. What do you mean when you say "polynomials that intersect the $x$-axis and the $yz$-plane"? The polynomials need to vanish on both of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although geometric intuition is essential, it's important to keep the two sides of the story (namely algebra and geometry) separate. When we take $V(\text{some polynomials})$, we are going from an algebraic object (in your case $\mathbf{C}[x,y,z]$) to a geometric object, which can safely be visualized as some subset of affine space being "cut out" by the polynomials. Conversely, $I(\text{some subset of affine space})$ takes us from a geometric object to an algebraic object, namely the ideal of polynomials vanishing on the given subset. This ideal carries no intrinsic geometric content, and should be treated as purely algebraic.

You might ask, "Well can't we graph a polynomial and think of its graph as a subset of affine space?" Technically yes, but this is the kind of thinking we want to distance ourselves from because we can already "graph" polynomials using $V$. You want to "graph" $y=x^2$? Just take $V(y-x^2)$. You want to "graph" $xyz = 1$? Just take $V(xyz-1)$. It's clear that we lose nothing by only considering the vanishing sets $V(\text{some polynomials})$, and so why not keep things as minimal as possible?

Comment: This was a good explanation! I was trying to get some intuitive understanding about $I(V)$, but apparently the intuitive idea is that it consists of all "polynomial consequences" of the set of polynomials which we're defining the variety over.